# IBM ILE RPG - How to store time values greater than 24h

Tags: rpgle

How can I store time values (e.g.: 33h 24m 02s) in a `TIME` variable since `*HIVAL` - the max value - is 24h 00m 00s.

When storing it in a data structure (DS) sometimes (when a values is less than 10) e.g: 33:24:03 the value is displayed as 33.24.3 since the field is not padding with zeros automatically

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well you have already answered your own question, the limit is 24 hours.

I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish, but I would suggest you use the [%diff()](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_72/rzasd/bbdif.htm) Built-in Function (BIF) to get the difference between the two time/date/timestamp values and store it in an integer. And then to manipulate another time/timestamp field you could use the [%seconds()](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_72/rzasd/bbsec.htm#bbsec) BIF.

For example:

```
       ctl-opt dftactgrp(*no) actgrp(*new);
       ctl-opt timfmt(*iso);

       dcl-s time1 time inz(t'09.25.00');
       dcl-s time2 time inz(t'10.00.00');
       dcl-s time3 time;
       dcl-s SecondsDiff int(10);
       dcl-s result char(1);

       SecondsDiff = %diff(time2: time1: *seconds);

       time3 = %time() + %seconds(SecondsDiff);

       dsply ('In 35 minutes it will be: ' + %char(time3)) '*EXT' result;

       *inlr = *on;
```

This is a very simplistic example, if you could give me more information to what you are trying to accomplish I could give a more specific example.

#### Edit

Here is a sample procedure that will do what you are requesting:

```
       ctl-opt dftactgrp(*no) actgrp(*new);

       dcl-s SecondsChar char(20);
       dcl-s Result varchar(32);
       dcl-s WaitAnyKey char(1);

       dsply 'Enter an amount of seconds: ' '*EXT' SecondsChar;

       Result = SecondsToDisplay(%int(SecondsChar));

       dsply Result '*EXT' WaitAnyKey;
       *inlr = *on;

       dcl-proc SecondsToDisplay;
         dcl-pi *n varchar(32);
           Seconds int(10) value;
         end-pi;

         dcl-s Result varchar(32) inz('');
         dcl-s CurrentValue int(10);

       Seconds = %abs(Seconds);

       //Get the days
       CurrentValue = Seconds / 86400;
       if (CurrentValue > 0);
         Result = %char(CurrentValue) + 'd ';
         Seconds = %rem(Seconds: 86400);
       endif;

       //Get the hours
       CurrentValue = Seconds / 3600;
       if (CurrentValue > 0 OR Result <> '');
         Result += %char(CurrentValue) + 'h ';
         Seconds = %rem(Seconds: 3600);
       endif;

       //Get the minutes
       CurrentValue = Seconds / 60;
       if (CurrentValue > 0 OR Result <> '');
         Result += %char(CurrentValue) + 'm ';
         Seconds = %rem(Seconds: 60);
       endif;

       //The seconds
       Result += %char(Seconds) + 's';


       return Result;

       end-proc;
```

And some sample output:

> DSPLY  Enter an amount of seconds: 799240
> DSPLY  9d 6h 0m 40s

Comment: I have to add up several time values (between a few minutes and 10 to 20 hours) and display the result. in my spcial case I get 33h and then there is an error

Comment: I already add them up, converting them in seconds. but in the end i want to re-convert it into *HMS. But how it seems, I have to format them by myselfe :(

Comment: @Radinator Yes, you'll have to format it yourself because you don't have a "time" value -- you have a "duration". There are built-in features for "time" such as *HMS for format. But a "duration" might have any number of forms, so you have to create whatever fits for you. Starting with number-of-seconds, a simple DOW-loop can subtract 3600 seconds each iteration to count hours, and a second DOW can subtract 60 from the remainder to count minutes. Or just use %DIV() and %REM() functions or the plain math that Adrian shows.